# Open outlook application from Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

Can anyone suggest ways to open Outlook client application from either a hyperlink. If you can suggest any webpart which maybe available to trial. I need to able to open Outlook.exe when a user click on an icon. this can either be using CEWP or an off-the-shelf webpart

Comment: in html you can <a href="mailto:user@gmail.com"><img src="youricon"/></a>

Comment: Thanks although I want outlook application to open similar to clicking the Outlook Icon from desktop. The mailto tag will open a new message window. I know there used to be webpart I could download, but cant find them anymore